# how to apply box-shadow on hexagon

Tags: html, css

i want to give box shadow on the hexagon

here is my jsfiddle 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oubmu9qu/6/)

and this is my hexagon css property

```
    .hex1 {
    background-color: rgba(52,152,219,.5);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 60px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px grey;
}
.hex1:before {
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid rgba(52,152,219,.5);
    top: -80px;
}
.hex1:after, .hex1:before {
    border-left: 70px solid transparent;
    border-right: 70px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.hex1:after {
    bottom: -80px;
    border-top: 40px solid rgba(52,152,219,.5);
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

this is not affecting on my hexagon .. is there any way to five border and box shadow to hexagon.
please help

Comment: Not that I know of. Depends on the look you are going for.

Comment: This is the reason why CSS shapes are a bad idea. You get the shape you want; great... but then you need to do something else with it, and it just gets harder and harder. Quit trying to get CSS to do things it isn't intended for (ie graphics) and just do the whole hexagon and shadow in SVG; it will be a whole lot quicker and easier and a lot more flexible.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle with what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/jdgraffam/G9MHj/1/ . NOT MY WORK, got it from: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/hexagon-with-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use these code....

```
 #hexagon{
   background: red;
   width: 100px; height: 60px;
   position: relative;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);   
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);   
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jelmerdemaat/5UMxW/3/